# How to set environmental variables properly Gitlab CI/CD and Docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am new to **Docker** and CI/CD with **Gitlab CI/CD**. I have `.env` file in the root directory of my Django project which contains my environmental variable e.g `SECRET_KEY=198191891`. The `.env` file is included in `.gitignore`. I have set up these variables in Gitlab settings for CI/CD. However, the environment variables set in Gitlab CI/CD settings seem to be unavailable

Also, how should the Gitlab CI/CD automation process create a user and DB to connect to and run the tests? When creating the DB and user for the DB on my local machine, I logged into the container `docker exec -it <postgres_container_name> /bin/sh` and created Postgres user and DB.

Here are my relevant files.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn writer.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
    environment:
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      SENDGRID_API_KEY: ${SENDGRID_API_KEY}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: ${AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/writer-api
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A writer worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/writer-api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A writer beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/writer-api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker-compose --version

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building the app"
    - docker-compose build

test:
  stage: test
  variables:
  script:
    - echo "Testing"
    - docker-compose run web coverage run manage.py test

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - echo "Deploying staging"
    - docker-compose up -d

deploy-production:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploying production"
    - docker-compose up -d
```

**Here are my settings for my variables**
[image]

**Here is my failed pipeline job**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SECRET_KEY` variable will be available to all your CI jobs, as configured. However, I don't see any references to it in your Docker Compose file to pass it to one or more of your services. For the web service to use it, you'd map it in like the other variables you already have.

```
  web:
    build: .
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn writer.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
      …
```

As for creating the database, you should wrap up whatever you currently run interactively in the postgres container in a SQL file or shell script, and then bind-mount it into the container's initialization scripts directory under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. See the [Initialization scripts](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres#initialization-scripts) section of the postgres image's description for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed my code later remove the hardcoded secret key and forgot to access it in `docker-compose.yml`. Which means if you haven't declared the variable in web container, then you cannot set it in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: Well, it's more that the GitLab CI variables are setting values in the runner's environment. Which you can then use however you wish. In this case, passing it to the environment specification for the web service.

Comment: Coming from an environment where I was manually doing a ssh into the remote server, doing a git pull and creating my `.env`, how do I separate development `.env` and a production `.env`. I used docker-machine to create an AWS EC2 instance. I created a `production.yml` and did `docker-compose -f production.yml up -d`. The container in the EC2 machine picked up my development `.env` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience the best way to pass environment variables to a container docker is creating an environment file, which works to development environment and production environment:

[GitLab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)

You must create an environment file on GitLab CI/CD, following the next steps, on your project GitLab you must go to:

`settings` > `CI/CD` > `Variables`

on that you must create a `ENV_FILE`

**Demo image**

[image]

Next on your build stage in `.gitlab-ci.yml` copy the ENV_FILE to local process

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cp $ENV_FILE .env
    - echo "Building the app"
    - docker-compose build
```

your `Dockerfile` should be stay normally so it doesn't have to change

**Dockerfile**

```yaml
FROM python:3.8.6-slim

# Rest of setup goes here...

COPY .env .env
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for compose variable substitution to work, when the user is not added to docker group, you must add the -E flag to sudo.

```
script:
        - sudo -E docker-compose build
```